# My NUC computer keeps freezing regularly. The syslog doesn't tell me anything

Tags: 16.04, kernel, freeze, intel-nuc

I'm sorry that i can't be more specific. It seems to freeze at completely random times and I haven't been able to associate it with temperature, the hard drive or other hardware. Here's the latest kernel oops

```
Nov 24 08:45:01 nuc CRON[17178]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425399] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425415] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 10703 at /build/linux-xHzv4a/linux-4.4.0/kernel/futex.c:1169 __unqueue_futex+0x58/0x60()
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425417] Modules linked in: rfcomm bluetooth xt_nat xt_tcpudp veth ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 xfrm_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 xt_addrtype iptable_filter ip_tables xt_conntrack x_tables nf_nat nf_conntrack br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs binfmt_misc intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_iosf intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul cryptd snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic joydev input_leds snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform lpc_ich snd_hda_intel snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec mei_txe snd_compress ac97_bus mei snd_hda_core snd_hwdep shpchp snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_timer snd soundcore snd_soc_sst_acpi mac_hid nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace sunrpc autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid uas usb_storage i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 mii drm pata_acpi fjes video
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425512] CPU: 0 PID: 10703 Comm: Threadpool work Not tainted 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425515] Hardware name: To be filled by O.E.M. To be filled by O.E.M./Aptio CRB, BIOS 5.6.5 10/23/2014
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425518]  0000000000000286 00000000fed1a706 ffff880062af3c90 ffffffff813f5aa3
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425524]  0000000000000000 ffffffff81cb9eb8 ffff880062af3cc8 ffffffff81081262
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425528]  ffffc90000736504 ffff880062af3da0 0000000000000000 ffffc90000736504
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425533] Call Trace:
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425542]  [] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425549]  [] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425553]  [] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425557]  [] __unqueue_futex+0x58/0x60
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425562]  [] futex_wait+0x143/0x280
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425567]  [] ? ttwu_do_wakeup+0x19/0xe0
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425572]  [] ? __hrtimer_init+0x90/0x90
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425577]  [] ? futex_wait_queue_me+0xa0/0x120
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425581]  [] do_futex+0x120/0x540
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425586]  [] SyS_futex+0x81/0x180
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425592]  [] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
Nov 24 08:53:03 nuc kernel: [335517.425596] ---[ end trace d92876be83213fc9 ]---
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. This has been this way for a long time (and in at least three Ubuntu versions)

Comment: It looks like it's failing in `/build/linux-xHzv4a/linux-4.4.0/kernel/futex.c:`, line `1169`. Inspect the source. Read `man -k futex`. What does "NUC" mean?

Comment: mine is `BOXNUC7i7BNH` and i have the same problem,  no solution yet.

Comment: @waltinator `NUC` is an intel product, a mini PC. it's the worst mini PC ever :(

Comment: @mohammadRaoofNia After I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 the computer has been working flawlessly (finally).

Comment: @DPA thanks. I'll try it and i hope it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a NUC6iSYH (a very small computer made by Intel). The kernel (64-bit) was not up to date so I updated & dist-upgraded it to the current one, the same as you are running. So far it works for me, but it is only sitting there (idle).

- Have you got the same or another model of NUC? Mine has an 6th generation i3 processor.
- Does it crash when you run some particular application program? Maybe I can try run to that program.
- Did you check what futex is doing? I looked it up:

  The futex() system call provides a method for waiting until a certain
         condition becomes true.  It is typically used as a blocking construct
         in the context of shared-memory synchronization.  When using futexes,
         the majority of the synchronization operations are performed in user
         space.  A user-space program employs the futex() system call only
         when it is likely that the program has to block for a longer time
         until the condition becomes true.  Other futex() operations can be
         used to wake any processes or threads waiting for a particular
         condition.

It seems from you output that bluetooth or the network might be involved. I am not using bluetooth, and I am using a wired network connection.

- Is there some special peripheral device?
- Could there be a problem with your RAM or some other hardware? You can check RAM with memtest, if you boot in BIOS mode.

-o-

Finally, I suggest that you create a bug report at ***Launchpad***. Solving this problem might need kernel programmers, and a bug report is the way to communicate with them.

Comment: I think I have some very old model "Intel Celeron N2810 Bay Trail M"

Comment: - I think I have some very old model "Intel Celeron N2810 Bay Trail M" 

- It might be connected to Kodi. At least it seems to happen more frequently when I'm watching something.

- I did not look up what futex was doing. Juding by what you posted I'm wondering if this has anything to do with my USB3 Raid box. 

- Like you I'm not using wifi or bluetooth, only ethernet.

Comment: It is possible, that the USB Raid box causes some waiting, and lack of synchronizing (problems with futex). This is beyond my knowledge. You can try with a previous kernel - and if it works, avoid upgrading it.